# Static allocation of c struct with variable length array

Tags: c, struct, allocation

I want to use a struct to store a variable length array of bytes (a UART message) and some other information/flags along with it such as length, what the message does etc. I have a struct defined:

```
typedef struct Message {
    int length;
    int otherInfo;
    char* bytes;
} Message;
```

And want to statically allocate an array of these structs which will correspond to certain messages (I have an enum to define the indexes) :

```
Message messages[] = {
    [UART_MESSAGE_TO_DO_X] = {
        .length = 16,
        .otherInfo = 10,
        .bytes = {
            0xB5, 0x62, //array of bytes that does X
            0x06, 0x01, 
            0x08, 0x00, 
            0xF0, 0x00, 
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
            0xFF, 0x23 
        }
    },
    [UART_MESSAGE_TO_DO_Y] = {
        .length = 20,
        .otherInfo = 15,
        .bytes = {
            0xB5, 0x62, //array of bytes that does Y
            0x06, 0x41, 
            0x0C, 0x00, 
            0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x1F, 0xC5, 0x90, 0xE1, 0x9F, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0xFF, 
            0x45, 0x79 
        }
    }
}
```

However this gives a warning "excess elements in scalar initializer" which I have looked up and seen solutions where the variable sized array is dynamically allocated and then assigned as a pointer, however I want to statically allocate as the values never change and I am working on a microprocessor with limited resources. I understand that a variable length array where the length isn't known can't be statically allocated, however in my case the length of each array is known and is constant, it is just that the length is not the same between instances of the stuct.

Comment: `with variable length array` where is the variable length array?

Comment: `.bytes = {... }` This would initialize an array member of your struct but you have a single pointer element. That is not a variable length array.

Comment: I think you mean a flexible array member (but they are in the form `char bytes[]` and can't be used as an array element). Can you try with compound literals `.bytes = (char []) {...}`?

Comment: An UART message is _never_ of unknown or variable size. There is a maximum buffer size that your program can reasonably handle. Either allocate enough static memory to handle that situation, or otherwise your program cannot handle UART, simple as that. This size is deterministic and can be determined by real-time calculations etc when designing the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> char* bytes;

It's a normal pointer. Allocate the array. Assign *the pointer*.

```
static char array[] = {
       0xB5, 0x62, //array of bytes that does X
       0x06, 0x01, 
       0x08, 0x00, 
       0xF0, 0x00, 
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
       0xFF, 0x23 
};    
static Message messages[] = {
    [UART_MESSAGE_TO_DO_X] = {
        .length = 16,
        .otherInfo = 10,
        .bytes = array,
    },
};
```

Or with a compound literal https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal . Watch out for the lifetime of a compound literal.

```
static Message messages[] = {
    [UART_MESSAGE_TO_DO_X] = {
        .length = 16,
        .otherInfo = 10,
        .bytes = (char[]){
            0xB5, 0x62, //array of bytes that does X
            0x06, 0x01, 
            0x08, 0x00, 
            0xF0, 0x00, 
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
            0xFF, 0x23 
        }
    },
};
```

A "variable length array" is a defined term - https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays . Your arrays seem to be constant in size.

Consider adding `const` if all the data are constant.

Comment: Thanks a compound literal is exactly what I was looking for I just didn't know the name for it. I believe the lifetime shouldn't be an issue as I allocate it at a global scope and as far as I can tell in C it will be given static storage duration, in C++ it seems this would have undefined behaviour.

Comment: K, "Assign the pointer." is better as "Initialize with the pointer." here as _assignment_ is a slightly different thing in C

Comment: And well I'm sure you already know that `char x = 0xB5;` etc is a rookie mistake. `char` should never be used at all when dealing with raw data. Please fix.